# Dynamically change url in facebook comments code

Tags: javascript, facebook

```
<div id="test1"><div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">
        </script>
        <fb:comments href="http://www.jewelryfresh.com/" num_posts="10" width="739"></fb:comments></div>
```

Above is the code for facebook comments box. I want to dynamically change the href value to the page on which it is. How can i do it.I do not want the static href value to the page on which it is. How can i do it.I do not want the static href value as it is now. Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `div` and then dynamically create its contents with the `innerHTML` method in JavaScript
where it will be your `fb:comments` tag. You can get the current page with `document.location.href`.

After you create the `fb:comments` tag dynamically and render it inside the `div`, you need to reparse its contents so the XFBML is interpreted. You can do it with the `FB.XFBML.parse(YOUR_DIV)` method.

Hope this helps.

```js
var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");  
mydiv.innerHTML = "<fb:comments href='" + document.location.href + "' num_posts='10' width='739'></fb:comments>";  
FB.XFBML.parse(mydiv);
```

Comment: @mangesh: No, yo do not work at facebook. You're only "app" developer . I am asking Anatoly

Comment: @genesis φ: I don't work for FB, but you can look at the old facebook developers forum if you need more info about me: anatolyl at forum.developers.facebook.com

Comment: @Anatoly no. I just see you posted a lot of FB answers in few minutes, so I though you're from FB